# Graphics.DrawImage doesn't seem to draw all shapes

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to draw an array of hexagons.
if I set the number of hexes above 7 it doesn't draw the 8th hex etc.
What's gone wrong?

[image: form graphics fail]

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1

    ' Dim pic As New List(Of PictureBox)
    Dim bm As New Bitmap(640, 480)
    Dim bmg As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm)
    Dim p As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black)
    Dim sb As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
  
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        p.Width = 5.0F
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim NumOfRaws As Integer = 8
        Dim hexRib As Integer = 40
        Dim LongSide As Integer = CInt(System.Math.Cos(30 * System.Math.PI / 180) * hexRib)
        Dim hexGap As Integer = 10
        For i = 0 To NumOfRaws - 1
            DrawHex(hexRib, CInt(hexGap * i + 100 + LongSide * (i * 2)), 100)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Sub DrawHex(ByVal side As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)
           Dim ShortSide As Integer = CInt(System.Math.Sin(30 * System.Math.PI / 180) * side)
        Dim LongSide As Integer = CInt(System.Math.Cos(30 * System.Math.PI / 180) * side)

        Dim Points(5) As Point
        Points(0) = New Point(x, y)
        Points(1) = New Point(x + LongSide, y + ShortSide)
        Points(2) = New Point(x + LongSide, y + ShortSide + side)
        Points(3) = New Point(x, y + ShortSide * 2 + side)
        Points(4) = New Point(x - LongSide, y + ShortSide + side)
        Points(5) = New Point(x - LongSide, y + ShortSide)

        p.Width = 5.0F
        bmg.DrawPolygon(p, Points)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, New Point(0, 0))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Try `bmg.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(Point.Empty, New Size(bm.Width - 1, bm.Height - 1)))` to see your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change as follows:

```
Dim p As Pen = New Pen(Color.Black)
Dim sb As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)

Dim bm As Bitmap '= New Bitmap(640, 480)
Dim bmg As Graphics '=  Graphics.FromImage(bm)


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    p.Width = 5.0F
    Dim NumOfRaws As Integer = 8
    Dim hexRib As Integer = 40
    Dim LongSide As Integer = CInt(System.Math.Cos(30 * System.Math.PI / 180) * hexRib)
    Dim hexGap As Integer = 10
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iMargin As Integer = 5

    bm = New Bitmap(NumOfRaws * 100, 480)
    bmg = Graphics.FromImage(bm)

    For i = 0 To NumOfRaws - 1
        DrawHex(hexRib, CInt(hexGap * i + 100 + LongSide * (i * 2)), 100)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot. so the problem was in the bitmap size.